# 苦しんでいる vs 苦しめられる

Tags: nuances, subsidiary-verbs, passive-form

次の文章を読んで、どう違いますか分かりません。

```
①　胃潰瘍に苦しんでいる。I suffer from stomach ulcer.
②　胃潰瘍に苦しめられる。I suffer from stomach ulcer.
```

両方は「胃潰瘍のせいで、僕は苦しんだ、今も苦しい」。
②は受身形で、「僕は苦しめられる、誰に？、胃潰瘍に」っていう意味でしょ？
それは Suffering Passive ですね。
意味は同じ見えるけど、特別で違うニュアンスはありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

アスペクトを「〜ている」で揃えれば、２つの文の意味に違いはありません。

> ①　胃潰瘍に苦しんでいる。
> ②　胃潰瘍に苦しめられている。

強いて言えば、受身文である②の方が主観的で、能動文である①の方が客観的な印象になります。自分自身のことを言う場合は②を使うことが多いように思います。文の主語である人自身が他動詞「苦しめる」の目的語に当たるので、迷惑受身ではなく普通の受身ですが、それでも話し手の「嫌だ」という感情が表れます。他の人について使った場合、話し手がその人の立場に立って苦しみを共感 (empathize) しているような印象に少しなります。

ただ、違いはわずかです。